# Basic ASP.NET MVC 3 Query

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

If i were to create a really really simple MVC3 web app, with the pages

http://localhost/home, http://localhost/b and http://localhost/c, does this mean creating three seperate controllers?

I was hoping to route all three through one controller with a seperate 'ActionResult' for each.

Thanks.

Comment: With MVC you don't create 'pages' .

Answer (score 6):

You can do that by adding a route for each URL to the same controller and different actions.

http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/creating-custom-routes-cs

Example:

```
routes.MapRoute( "home", "{action}",
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = "" });
```

That will route to actions called "home" "b" and "c".

Although I wouldn't do it.  I tend to always have a controller and action as it makes categorisation of concerns easier later.

Comment: +1 When I have a need to do something like this in MVC, I tend to make it the last route definition possible to prevent it catching others unintentionally.

Comment: for some reason routing is confusing, if you run into trouble get the 'routedebugger' package using Nuget

Answer (score 0):

Yeah you can add routes and use the same controller.

But I like my controllers to represent related work.  So for example an account controller would have a login, registeration and signup.  CustomerController might have list, create, edit, delete.